# c3p0 is unable to make connection with mysql database - access denied

Tags: mysql, c3p0

I am unable to get connection from mysql database, though I can connect to the database using the userId and password.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root '@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2397)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
```

Here is command prompt connection

```
Ashishs-MacBook-Pro:~ atyagi$ mysql --user=root --password=pass sample
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 643
Server version: 5.5.34 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Comment: Says `user 'root '@'localhost'` - you sure you don't have an extra space after `root `?

Comment: No. I have checked my property file and it does not have any space after root.

Comment: Don't know what else to tell you, maybe you're loading the property somewhere and it's getting a space added to it?  We'd need more info to help you.  Can you provide your config properties file?